# using Samson GTrack USB mic on ubuntu

Tags: usb, microphone

welcome,
I want anyone help me to make my new USB mic works on ubuntu.
Mic : Samson GTrack , Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have everything updated involving sound management:

`sudo apt-get install asoundconf-gtk alsa-oss libasound2 libasound2-plugins padevchooser gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Then go to System -> Preferences -> Sound and choosing "USB Audio Codec USB Audio (ALSA)," under Audio Conferencing -> Sound Capture. Click "Test" to test out the microphone.

Comment: i got this error when i enter this line to terminal
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package padevchooser is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package asoundconf-gtk
E: Package 'padevchooser' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 0):

i am using ubuntu 13.04 and using a samsung g-track. plugged in g-track. and went to sound settings and then went to anolog output pcm2904 audio codec. can now hear headset through my gtrack mic. and also turned up mic and can hear myself sing with the music. have yet to try to record to see if mic makes a difference in recording so i can get a fuller and louder output. i hope this works for you g-track users. just do your recording with head sets on and then see how it sounds on play back with out the anolog out put on so you can hear it through the speaker built in audio.

Comment: actually when u unplug samsun g-track it goes back to speaker built in audio

Answer (score 0):

I searched more and I found this page in audacity's documentation and it looks like this USB microphone should work using linux: 
https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/overdubbing_with_a_samson_g_track_usb_microphone.html